# Pandas groupby with minimal group size

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, grouping

I have a dataframe `df` of shape (450 000, 15), containing informations about users, and each line is a different user, with 13 characteristics(age, gender, home-town...) and 1 boolean variable, whether the user has or doesn't have a car.

I would like to regroup my users to find out which groups have the most cars, but I need to keep at least 2500 users in a group to keep it statistically relevant.

```
test= df.groupby(['Gender'])
test.size() # check the groups size
```

> ```
> Gender
> Female    150000
> Male      300000
> dtype: int64
> ```

So far so good, I have way more than 2500 user by groups. So I had another grouping criteria :

```
test2= df.groupby(['Gender','Age'])  
test2.size()
```

> ```
> Gender   Age
> Female   <30     15022
>          30-90   134960
>          90+     18
> Male     <20     5040
>          20-90   291930
>          90+     3030    
> dtype: int64
> ```

As we can expect, I now have groups with very little users...

I would like to have something like this :

> ```
> Gender   
> Female   150 000 # Don't split here because groups will be too small
>
> # Here I can split, because group size > 2500 :
> Gender   Age
> Male     <20     5040 
>          20-90   291930
>          90+     3030    
> dtype: int64
> ```

I didn't find a way to group a groupby dataframe based on a size criteria, so I was wondering what would be a pythonic way to handle this.

As I have 13 characteristics to group my users, I am also wondering about the grouping order : should I group by gender first and then by age, or the opposite? This has an impact when using multiple variables with a stop condition.

I don't need to use pandas, but I thought it would be appropriate. The output should look like :

```
name_of_group  group_size
Female         150000
Male, <20      5040
Male, 20-90    291930
Male, 90+      3030
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`groupby` has to group on a "key" which must be separately computable for each row.  That is, there's no way to group by some criterion that depends on aggregate characteristics that you won't know until after the group is created (like its size).  You could write code that tries different groupings and uses some heuristic to decide which is "best", but there's nothing built in for this.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want all the groups to have at least 2500 users?

You could so something like this:

```
# List of all sets of categories you want to test
group_ids_list = [['Gender'], ['Age'], ['Gender','Age']]
# Will be filled with groups that pass your test
valid_groups = []
group_sizes = {}

for group_ids in group_ids_list :

    grouped_df = df.groupby(group_id)
    for key, group in grouped_df:
        if len(group) > 25000:
            valid_groups.append(group)
            group_sizes[key] = len(group) 

group_sizes = pd.Series(group_sizes)
```

And then you can work using only the valid groupers.
Hope the pseudo-code helps, otherwise please provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

I think FLab's answer is probably more complete and correct. But if you're after a quick fix;

```
column = 'Gender'
minimum_size = 2500

valid_groups = [g for g in set(df[col]) if sum(df[col] == g) >= minimum_size]
mask = df[column].isin(valid_groups)
df[mask].groupby(column)
```